# Why is Steam asking for a verification code when I don't have Steam Guard?

Tags: steam

Steam had an update and I had to log in again.  Once I logged in, a window popped up asking for an email verification code.  The header on the window said "Steam Guard."  I don't have steam guard enabled on my account.  Why is it asking for a verification?

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is actually Steam?

Comment: It could be just the title of the window. Steam guard I thought was the random letters/numbers produced in the the Steam mobile app. It sounds like if you don't have the app/Steam guard, it just sends you an email with a code instead?

Answer (score 11):

According to a [Steam Guard](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/06b0-26e6-2cf8-254c#enableemail) post:

> **Steam Guard is enabled by default** on your Steam account if your email is verified and you have restarted Steam twice on your computer since verifying your email.

It sounds like you've been "auto-enrolled" into this form of Steam Guard.

Comment: would this only be true if I had only recently verified my email?  Because I have been using steam a long time and steam guard has been off, or at least I didn't have to verify my email when logging in.

Comment: @Millard I can't say for sure.  Where are you seeing this Steam Guard setting? Maybe add a screenshot of it?

Comment: @Millard I did also read something about it sending you an email if you signed on to a "new device" (one Steam doesn't recognize you signing in from).   I wonder if the update you speak of made Steam forget your device or something.

Comment: well i can confirm that steam guard has been enabled somehow, I tried signing in through my browser and was asked to verify through email.  Again, it said it was steam guard, and that "You have an email authenticator protecting this account."  I'm still not sure how this got enabled tho